# optimization of prime number generator further

Tags: python, optimization, generator

Python program to print the list of Prime number to a given limit, but the catch is that it has to print them by skipping a step.
it means that prime number till 20 will be : 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19

but I have to print them by skipping a number that means: 2 5 11 17

but using python generator function:
I have written the code down below but **I want to ask that is there any other way or can I further optimize it.**

```
def prime(n):
  lst = []
  newlist = []
  if n == 1:
       pass
       for i in range(2,n):
           for j in range(2,i//2+1):
                if i%j==0:
                   break
       else:
           lst.append(i)

  length = len(last)
  newlist = lst[0:length:1]


  for m in newlist:
     yield m 


for i in prime(20):
   print(i)
```

Comment: Look into the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 0):

**Improvements**

- Only need to check for a divisor up to sqrt(n) (this changes algorithmn complexity to O(n*sqrt(n)) rather than O(n^2)
- Only need to check if prime odd numbers after two
- Use a flag to toggle on every prime detection as an efficient way to decide which primes to report (avoids having to save primes in a list reducing storage complexity from O(n/ln n) to O(1)).

**Code**

```
def prime(n):
  '''
      Report every other prime up to n
  '''
  if n < 2:
    return  # No primes

  yield 2   # First prime (only even prime, rest are odd)
  
  report = False     # Report flag (toggle on each prime)
  for candidate in range(3, n, 2):
    # Check only odd numbers
    for divisor in range(2, int((candidate**0.5) + 1)):
        if candidate % divisor == 0:
            break
    else:
        # No divisors found so prime (i.e. did not hit break)
        if report:    # Report this prime
            yield candidate
            
        report = not report   # Toggle report flag (don't report next prime)
                     
for i in prime(20):
   print(i, end = ' ')

# Out: 2 5 11 17
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach this would be to create a prime generator function that yields all the primes and use it in a separate iterator function that returns every other value.

Unless there is some meaningful optimization to obtain from specialization, having a base function without specialized constraints is generally more useful than hyper specializing one function. (for example, you could reuse the prime generator to get squares of primes or to create a prime factorization function).

For example:

```
def allPrimes(toN):
    isPrime = [True]*(toN+1) # sieve or Erathosthenes
    if toN>=2: yield 2
    for p in range(3,toN+1,2):
        if not isPrime[p]: continue
        yield p
        isPrime[p*p::2*p] = [False]*len(range(p*p,toN+1,2*p))


def otherPrimes(toN):
    for i,p in enumerate(allPrimes(toN)):
        if i%2==0: yield p
```

output:

```
print(*allPrimes(100))
print(*otherPrimes(100))

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
2 5 11 17 23 31 41 47 59 67 73 83 97
```

Note that there is already a function (`islice`) that does the equivalent of the `otherPrimes` function in the itertools module.

```
from itertools import islice
print(*islice(allPrimes(100),0,None,2)) # every other value from generator
2 5 11 17 23 31 41 47 59 67 73 83 97
```